# How to alias keybindings in emacs?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, key-binding

For instance, I get to use <kbd>C-c a a</kbd> a lot, and would like to easily map this to <kbd>f1</kbd>.

I know I can search for what function the first binding finaly calls (this time it was `org-agenda-list`), but I'm after a more general solution. I don't think I can use `(global-set-key KEY COMMAND)`, for I'm not sure if pressing keys is a `COMMAND` in itself (but maybe it can be?)

**So how to bind "multiple successive keypresses" to another binding?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you are looking for is:

```lisp
(define-key keymap-1 (kbd "new prefix")
 (lookup-key keymap-2 (kbd "old prefix")))
```

You don't usually need to know the names of the keymaps as the expressions
`(current-global-map)` and `(current-local-map)` return the global and local maps in
force. Although the emacs manual says you can re-map any of the function keys, I have found that strange things can happen if you try to re-map f1, f2, f3, f4 or f10. For this reason I usually re-map f5 or f6. As an example from my .emacs file, the code:

```lisp
(add-hook 'planner-mode-hook
    #'(lambda ()
        (local-set-key (kbd "M-RET") 'muse-insert-list-item)
        (local-set-key (kbd "M-S-RET") 'pcomplete)
        (define-key (current-local-map) (kbd "&lt;f5&gt;")
          (lookup-key (current-local-map) (kbd "C-c C-j")))))
```

sets <kbd>M-RET</kbd> and <kbd>M-S-RET</kbd> in planner-mode and also makes the prefix
<kbd>f5</kbd> into an alias for <kbd>C-c C-j</kbd> in that mode.

Be aware, however, that it doesn't
always work as `lookup-key` seem understand macros which, unfortunately, are
legal in keymaps. In such cases you can usually find a way round it. Ask again if
you have problems.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're mentionning prefixes, but this works, and the hook idea is interesting (even though i'm more familiar with knowing how keymaps are called). I donk know much about macros, the bright side being I therefore don't care (I mean, if that's the `C-x (` / `C-x )` thing, mapping constructs based on them to other bindings seems very deviant to me >_<). Are you running in problems with f1 to f4 and f10 because they're already bound, sometimes later defined than your own definition, by any chance ?

Comment: Some major modes rebind them. For instance f1 is bound to help but some major modes have their own variant of help and re-bind the key. I find it easier not to use them.

Answer (score -1):

I think, but didn't try, that you should do something like this:

```
(defun org-execute-my-action ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-c q") 'org-name-of-function))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-execute-my-action)
```

[This post](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/02/08/mastering-key-bindings-emacs/) seems to be the place for further details.

Comment: Err, I don't see how that's adressing my question… That's merely binding a key locally in the org-mode-map, right? I'd like to bind a one key to "multiple keypresses". (For instance, there is no place for `f1` in you example.)